How to get a date displayed if a value is accumulated in a Pandas dataframe?
I'm sure this will be an easy answer for any Python pro, but I am new.
I have some vending machine sales data. My goal is to find the number of days it takes for the best-selling item, 142, to sell out all of the 18 cans in the machine. I am trying to iterate over the data to find the date of when the total item quantity item 142 is equal to 18.
Here is a sample set of data, hard to put into text form:
        Day         Hour of Day Item    Trans Type Item Quantity Day of the Week
0   2024-04-01  01:00:00    110 Credit (EMV Contactless)    1   0
1   2024-04-01  01:00:00    133 Credit (EMV Contactless)    1   0
2   2024-04-01  09:00:00    123 Cash    1   0
3   2024-04-01  09:00:00    125 Cash    1   0
4   2024-04-01  09:00:00    137 Cash    1   0
5   2024-04-01  13:00:00    142 Cash    1   0
6   2024-04-01  19:00:00    140 Cash    1   0
7   2024-04-01  19:00:00    142 Cash    1   0
8   2024-04-01  19:00:00    143 Cash    1   0
9   2024-04-01  20:00:00    142 Cash    1   0

Here is my current code that gives an error:
for amt in april['Item Quantity']:
    if april['Item'] == 142:
        total += april['Item Quantity']
       if total > 18:
        print(april.loc[amt, ['Day']])
        break


Your question is unclear, first provide a [mre] with enough items 142 to demonstrate the logic. What happens if you have less that 18 of those items? And more? Also make sure to provide the exact expected output in all those cases.

In addition to including a minimal working example and the exact expected output, it's also good to include the exact error you are receiving.

Example Code
import pandas as pd
data = {'Day': ['2024-04-01', '2024-04-01', '2024-04-01', '2024-04-01', '2024-04-01', '2024-04-01', '2024-04-01', '2024-04-01', '2024-04-01', '2024-04-01'], 'Hour of Day': ['01:00:00', '01:00:00', '09:00:00', '09:00:00', '09:00:00', '13:00:00', '19:00:00', '19:00:00', '19:00:00', '20:00:00'], 'Item': [110, 133, 123, 125, 137, 142, 140, 142, 143, 142], 'Trans Type': ['Credit (EMV Contactless)', 'Credit (EMV Contactless)', 'Cash', 'Cash', 'Cash', 'Cash', 'Cash', 'Cash', 'Cash', 'Cash'], 'Item Quantity': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 'Day of the Week': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df:

Code
In your example, finding the datetime that item 142 has a quantity equal to 18 is not reproducible. The code below finds the datetime that item 142 has a quantity equal to 2. If you want 18, modify the variable n below.
item, n = 142, 2
idx = df.loc[df['Item'].eq(item), 'Item Quantity'].cumsum().eq(n).idxmax()

idx:
7

chk datetime in text form
out = df.loc[idx].pipe(lambda x: x['Day'] + ' ' + x['Hour of Day'])

out
'2024-04-01 19:00:00'

'2024-04-01 19:00:00' is the datetime(in text format) when item 142 has a cumulative quantity of 2 in the example.
